# Pitch shifting effects on formants

Tags: matlab, audio, pitch

[image]I am doing a project for uni where i try to change the precieved gender of an audio using dsp techniques on matlab i started with pitch and am trying to move to formants now but i am not sure i fully understand the concepts.

I saw that changing pitch (i used a phacevocoder and then resampled the output) also effects the formants, but i am unsure if that is a bad change. I saw that it mainly shifted the frquencies to the left lowering the frequencies and kept the amplitudes basically the same.

Is my job now to just lower or increase the amplitude of the spectrum to finish this step or do i need to find a way to keep the old envelope of the audio and then change the amplitudes to make this more realistic and correct.

Unsure if I explained everything correctly but if you need more information lmk, and thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to SP SE! This is a complicated project. I suggest starting with doing some research on the differences between male and female voice. Unfortunately this may depend on the specific language and sometimes even on the specific vowel. Formants and fundamental frequency do NOT shift uniformly (for example in English and French the $f_1$ formant is the same for females and males but the $f_2$ and $f_3$ formants are significantly higher. A simple pitch shift is unlikely to work here. See for example: https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00764811/document

Comment: Thanks but i did look up the differences and I am not creating a universal algorithm. it will be two sentences in english. I wanted to understand how formants are effected by that change. And an idea how to continue. But thanks I will check the paper out

Comment: Okay, I might suggest to take a look at [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255966071_A_Detailed_Analysis_of_a_Time-Domain_Formant-Corrected_Pitch-Shifting_Algorithm).  Now this is a time-domain algorithm, ***not*** the phase-vocoder.  It needs a good pitch detector to sound good.  But you will be able to control the pitch shift and the formant shift separately.  In the 1990's IVL had a patent on one or two methods of implementing this but I think the patents are expired.

Comment: @3izmanique: If you pitch shift with a regular pitch shifter all components (fundamental, $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$) will shift by the same amount (in octaves). It easy enough to determine whether this is "good enough" for your project: just pop it in Audacity (or a similar DAW), play around with the pitch shifter and take a listen. If you like what you hear, you are done.